# Why does installing numpy using pip fail, while building directly does not?

Tags: python, numpy, pip, python-3.3

I'm trying to install `numpy` under Python 3.3.0 running Mac OS 10.7.5 (Lion) and using the compilers that come with Xcode 4.5.1. I installed Python 3 and `gfortran` using `homebrew` without any hiccups, but `pip3 install numpy` fails. Looking at other suggestions online, I tried setting Clang as the C compiler using:

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang
export FFLAGS=-ff2c
```

but received the same error. The final line reports `ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached`, and I [posted the full output](https://gist.github.com/3996080).

So, instead I tried building directly from source using the [instructions from SciPy.org](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X). This appears to succeed; the build and install processes run to completion, although they are not shy about reporting warnings. The full log is again [available as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/3996140). I can then run `numpy.test('full')` from Python 3, and although there are some warnings about unclosed files that I don't understand, it [reports that all tests pass](https://gist.github.com/3996163).

Does anyone know why pip fails to build NumPy when I can apparently do it manually without a problem?

Comment: I don't know about compiling especially on Mac, but doesn't pip3 get the 1.6 version while you basically compiled the 1.7 version? That could be a difference...

Comment: @seberg That's a great point, and when I try to compile the 1.6.2 version myself it does indeed fail. So that answers why `pip` was behaving differently; now I need to figure out why the build of SciPy is failing. Thanks!

Comment: I get exactly the same error in Arch Linux.

Comment: This is https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/359

Comment: Use homebrew! It will help you a lot on developing under Mac Os. http://brew.sh/ You will not face this kind problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like numpy now provides wheels on pypi, which should install correctly without needing to compile anything locally on your machine when using pip.