# How to install Numpy & Scipy for Python 3.3 on Moutain Lion

Tags: python, macos, numpy, scipy

Haven't found a working solution as of yet. I have three different versions of Python on my system, the default bundled with OSX (2.7.2), 2.7.3 installed via homebrew and 3.3.0 installed via homebrew. Running `pip install numpy` or `pip install scipy` will install it for the 2.7.3 version.

How can I install numpy and scipy for Python 3.3.0 on Moutain Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call **pip3** instead of pip. Homebrew installs pip3 with python3.

I just tried `pip3 install numpy` on my OSX 10.7.5 python 3.3.0 machine and it failed. It looks like numpy v1.6 is not compatible but numpy v1.7 (beta, not available via pip3) is.

Link: A post on SO:
[Why does installing numpy using pip fail while building directly does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184826/why-does-installing-numpy-using-pip-fail-while-building-directly-does-not)